# Why is only a part of my list written to an output file? (Python)

Tags: python

I have written a one hot encoding program, and the output is exactly as it should be when displayed in the Linux shell (or when standard output is redirected using ">"). However, I would like to implement some Python code which will redirect the output into a new file. I have not been able to find any answers to this problem on StackOverflow which deals with the specific output of multiple lists.

I'm not sure how much code is needed for context, but this is what an example of my output looks like:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

And this is the part of the code in which these lists are compiled:

```
encoded = list()
for value in integer_encoded:
    base = [0 for x in range(len(bases))]
    base[value] = 1
    encoded.extend(base)
print(encoded)

import sys
sys.stdout = open("output", "w")
print(encoded)
sys.stdout.close()
```

However, my "output" file only contains the last list, and I cannot work out why this is happening. I would really appreciate some advice on how to get my entire output to print to this file.

Comment: Please do not overwrite sys.stdout. Use `with open(path, "w") as file: file.write(content)`

Comment: use `open("output", "w")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand, but I'll try to help.

It might help knowing what `integer_encoded` and `bases` are.

Either way, to write to a file:

`with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(encoded))`

Comment: Thank you Jamesdeluk, the problem with this is that I get an error: ```TypeError: expexted a string or other character buffer object```. This is a one hot encoder for DNA bases, so ```bases = "ATCG"```, and these bases are then enumerated from 1 to 4.  ```integer_encoded``` holds the DNA sequence letters encoded as these numbers, which are then translated to 0 and 1 in the above code. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Did you try str()?

Comment: Yes I have thank you, and I no longer have that error message. However, it is still the same problem where only the last list is written to the output file. Therefore, I think the issue is with where this part of the code is placed and I should try to make it iterate over the outputs somehow.

Comment: Then you'll have to incorporate the file.write within the for loop. Does each loop create one list?

Comment: Yes, each loop creates one list.